# How do I show the sum of multiple ranges in one cell?

Tags: numbers

How do I show the sum of multiple ranges in one cell? I want to add the sum of C5:C25 to the sum of G5:G25 and divide the answer by 14.

Answer (score 3):

```
=(SUM(C5:C25)+SUM(G5:G25))/14
```

SUM function takes a range. + operator adds the results. / operator divides.

Comment: Thanks very much. I pasted this in and bingo.  The formula isn't a problem for me, the thing is I struggle too create it from scratch without getting a syntax error that tells me the range I put in 'cannot be used as a single value'.  It seems to relate to the closing bracket, which I can only get to show as 1/4 moon rather than ')'.

Comment: @Rick Rather than typing these manually, you should use the interactive selection to create your formula. Type SUM, press Enter to select the autocomplete, then use the mouse to drag over the range, which will insert the range appropriately into the formula. If an answer solves your problem, you can accept it using the check mark on the left.